# Is there a simple way to invert substrings using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, substring

I am manipulating some strings which contain a number and characters. Input strings are such `elementX5`, `elementX50` and so on. I know how to 
change them `elements_10`, `elements_100` etc. with the following code:

```
import re

inp = ["elementX5asdl", "elementX50al;smd;l", "elementX500laknsd", "elementX5000aknsd"]
for el in inp:
    tmp_usr_str = re.search("elementX50*", el).group()
    tmp_usr_str = re.sub(r"elementX", "elements_", tmp_usr_str)
    tmp_usr_str = re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: str(2*int(x.group())), tmp_usr_str)
    print(tmp_usr_str)
```

I would like to go a step further by inverting the substring containing the number with the substring containing letters to obtain something like: `10_elements`, `100_elements` and so on.

I know I can split the string and then compose it again but is there a more elegant way using regular expressions, possibly embedding the command in one of the already existing lines?

Comment: Did you try formulating a regular expression to achieve the same?

Comment: No because I do not where to start: I know how to use `re.sub` for substitution of one or more substring but not for inversions

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean by "invert".

Comment: OP means "swap", not "invert", the sample input (`elementX5`) and expected output (`10_elements`) implies that

Comment: @martineau Did you even read the question? I gave the examples with the inputs and desired outputs and that is exactly what I meant. Maybe invert is not the right term: swap maybe?

Comment: I don't know, it looks to me one could just take the number and use `{}_elements.format(number)` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capturing groups:

```
import re

inp = ["elementX5asdl", "elementX50al;smd;l", "elementX500laknsd", "elementX5000aknsd"]
for el in inp:
    tmp_usr = re.search("elementX50*", el)
    if tmp_usr:
        tmp_usr_str = tmp_usr.group()
        tmp_usr_str = re.sub(r"(element)X(\d+)", lambda x: "{}_{}s".format(str(2*int(x.group(2))), x.group(1)), tmp_usr_str)
        print(tmp_usr_str)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Jtuwbh). Output:

```
10_elements
100_elements
1000_elements
10000_elements
```

**Details**

- `tmp_usr = re.search("elementX50*", el)` - extracts the substring you need
- `re.sub(r"(element)X(\d+)", lambda x: "{}_{}s".format(str(2*int(x.group(2))), x.group(1)), tmp_usr_str)` - matches and captures `element` into Group 1 and `\d+` captures into Group 2 one or more digits after `X`, and inside the lambda expression, swaps the group values joining them with `_` and appending `s` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most easiest of regexes to write.

`(.*)_(.*)`

this captures everything before `_` in `\1` and everything after `_` in `\2`.

All you have to do is replace the two groups while substituting:

`\2_\1`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nNOhec/1)